# Add and Remove duplicate Classes

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I have a function that when the user hovers over a button, the class with the bg fadesOut and the hover class fadesIn. I also want the text colour to change and this is within the button under a h3 class but can't seem to trigger the event.

I've tried $(this).find('h3')removeClass('grey'); but no luck!

Here is my html and jQuery for the background to work, maybe i am not calling it properly using the parent and children events?

HTML

```
<div class="cta light-grey-bg">
   <h3 class="uppercase grey center">
   PHP Anchor link here
   </h3>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.cta').hover(function(){
   $(this).removeClass('light-grey-bg', 800);
   $(this).addClass('light-grey-bg-fade', 400);

}, function(){
   $(this).addClass('light-grey-bg', 400);
   $(this).removeClass('light-grey-bg-fade', 800);
});
```

As i said the function above works but no luck with removing the h3 class grey? Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: There is no second argument here: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: @Cherniv no but looks like it work as animation duration used with jquery UI http://jsfiddle.net/T2Q2K/   http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/

Comment: That's not a second argument.  that's if you pass a function to it. e.g. `$(this).removeClass(function(index, previous){ /*here you can work with the index and previous class name as well as set a new one*/ });`

Comment: just an FYI.. you can use [.switchClass()](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchClass/) instead of `removeClass()` and `addClass()` which does the same thing.. except you will have the same animation duration for both :) [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zhDjk/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error

```
$(this).find('h3').removeClass('grey'); //missing .
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qwv3x/)

Ex:

```
$('.cta ').hover(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('light-grey-bg', 800).addClass('light-grey-bg-fade', 400).find('h3').removeClass('grey'); 

}, function(){
    $(this).addClass('light-grey-bg', 400).removeClass('light-grey-bg-fade', 800).find('h3').addClass('grey'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of rules of thumb first:

- Never use spaces in selectors unless you need them
- Always reference your element instead of re-fetching it from the DOM

Next, you're using `removeClass` and `addClass` as if they had 2nd arguments, which they do not, as the API documentation clearely states:

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/
http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Note that the 2nd argument is only used in jQuery UI, which means duration, alonside with other properties, similar to jQuery's native `animate` function (you didn't specify you're using UI).
http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/

You can however add or remove mroe classes at once, simply delimit them by a space, like so:

```
$element.addClass('one two three four');
```

Now, on to your solution:

You are selecting your parent ".cta", which is fine, but you're toggling that elements classes. Your provided solution should work fine...

```
var $cta = $('.cta'),
    $h3 = $cta.find('h3');

$cta.hover(
    function() {
        $h3.toggleClass('light-grey-bg light-grey-fade');
    },
    function() {
        $h3.toggleClass('light-grey-bg light-grey-fade');
    }
);
```

See where I am re-using $cta and $h3? That's a lot more browser friendly. Besides that, you'd be safer off, if your documents classes are inconsistant, by still using `add-` and `removeClass` instead of `toggleClass`.

Comment: Sorry i have included jQuery UI so duration so i am able to use the argument.